# .designer.vb does not show up in solution explorer (VS 2017 community)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a windows form program with many forms in it, and the majority of the forms have all three files: `.desinger.vb`, `.resx` and `.vb`.

Some of my forms only have `.resx` and `.vb`. The `.designer.vb`  is missing even though I show all files in solution explorer.

How do I get back the `designer.vb` form for a specific form. I have enclosed a picture of my IDE and you will see that `stockcapture.vb` and `stockcapture.resx` exist, however `stockcapture.designer.vb` is missing.

Note: The project compiles and runs perfectly. I am just worried about the missing designer file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience this can happen if you insert code into the designer.vb form other then that which is auto generated.

You will have to do this outside the compiler using something like notepad++ to cut and paste. Cut out the #design region out of the stockcapture.vb file (as in your case) and create a new file called stockcapture.designer.vb wherein you insert this code.

Don't forget to include the following on top of your form :-

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class StockCapture
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub
```

Now open your project again in Visual Studio and then right click on the new file you created (stockcapture.designer.vb) and include it to the project.

Now when you click on stockcapture.vb you may initially get error messages attributed to the code (#design) that you removed but this will go away as soon as you click back to the stockcapture.designer.vb form.